# Out of memory permgen space when running as service

Tags: java, jvm, report, permgen

I have Jboss 7.1.1 AS and when I run it as service, after some time when I use jasper reports I get exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Notice that this does not happen at all when I run it from Jboss developer studio.

What should I do ?

Error stack:

```
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2585) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2885) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:350) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:399) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator$1.run(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:396) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generate(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:395) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.MethodAccessorGenerator.generateSerializationConstructor(MethodAccessorGenerator.java:113) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at sun.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newConstructorForSerialization(ReflectionFactory.java:331) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.getSerializableConstructor(ObjectStreamClass.java:1376) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.access$1500(ObjectStreamClass.java:72) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:493) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$2.run(ObjectStreamClass.java:468) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.<init>(ObjectStreamClass.java:468) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.lookup(ObjectStreamClass.java:365) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:602) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1622) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1990) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1915) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1798) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:249) [jasperreports-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRLoader.loadObject(JRLoader.java:233) [jasperreports-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.SerializedObjectPersistenceService.load(SerializedObjectPersistenceService.java:59) [jasperreports-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.SerializedReportPersistenceService.load(SerializedReportPersistenceService.java:43) [jasperreports-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
    at net.sf.jasperreports.repo.DefaultRepositoryService.getResource(DefaultRepositoryService.java:155) [jasperreports-5.6.1.jar:5.6.1]
```

Comment: We don't have magic ball in hand. Give us more details.

Comment: you should set permgen space to a higher amount ;)

Comment: I thought about that, setting it from standalone.conf.bat but this does not solve the issue. Why it happens only when run as service ?

Comment: Increase the PermSize. You could notice that the problem disappears with Java 8, it doesn't have Perm Gen anymore (now called metaspace and it's just part of the usual heap).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to raise the **PermSize** for your JBoss in the `standalone.conf.bat` that's inside the bin folder of your server.

Find set "`JAVA_OPTS=-Xms64M -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M`" and change the **MaxPermSize** as per your requirement.

I don't know much about developer studio, but it probably sets the PermGem for the server ignoring the standalone.conf.bat (with a higher value), thus your report works.

BUT, you need to search for any leaks in your report that may be causing that **OutOfMemoryError**.

Hope it helps.